# check the url params in jquery and append something to the url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there a way to check the url params in jquery and append something to the url with refreshing the url.
So if current url path is:

http://someurl.com/test/

```
function myView() {
  // if url does not have params of view='list' {
    // update the url with http://someurl.com/test/&view=list
  } else {
    //dont update
  }
}
```

Comment: html5 history api, learn about it.

Comment: i am looking into it. But i would need to support some older browsers as well.

Comment: That is impossible in older browsers.

Comment: ok i will look into html5 history to append url params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var url= $(location).attr('href');
 var val = url.indexOf('view');

    if (val < 0) {

        url += "?view=list";
        window.location = url;
    }
```

Check the article using Push and PopState: 
http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9940/